# Batch command using both wait and timeout

Tags: batch-file, installation, windows-installer

I'm trying to install multiple programs one after another. How can I wait for one app's setup to finish, and terminate if it lasts over 600 seconds?

Here's my code so far:

```
ECHO "Installing 7-Zip 16.04 (x64 edition)"
START "7-Zip 16.04 (x64 edition)" /WAIT msiexec -i "7z1604-x64.msi" /qn
ECHO "Installing Foxit Reader"
START "Foxit Reader" /WAIT "FoxitReader821_enu_Setup.msi" /verysilent
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `pslist` from `PsTools` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/pstools to check if the process is running.

```
:ZIPCHECK
REM Use the actual process name here, obviously
pslist /accepteula | findstr /I "7\-zip" > file.txt
set INS_PRCNAM=
for /F "tokens=1" %%A in (file.txt) do set INS_PRCNAM=%%A
if "%INS_PRCNAM%" == "" goto ZIPDONE
REM Put timer logic here, including either a sleep.exe or sleep.ps1 utility
goto ZIPCHECK
:ZIPDONE

REM Cleanup
:ENDIT
if EXIST file.txt del /Q file.txt
set INS_PRCNAM=
```

Timer logic you can find elsewhere, but usually makes use of the `%DATE%` and `%TIME%` environment variables and the text-modification features of the `SET` command, as well as the arithetic support from `SET /A`.

Termination could be accomplished by the `pskill` utility, also from the `PsTools` kit.

Alternatively, you could user PowerShell:

```
powershell "Get-Process -Name '7-Zip'" > file.txt
```

Comment: seems like antiviruses doesn't like it. thank you for your answer.

Comment: As these are standard tools, I'd be inclined to submit a "False Positive" report to your antivirus vendor.  Could get you up and running within a week.

Comment: I've added a note about how to do it with PowerShell.  You could expand on that and do all the work in PowerShell, but the one-liner shown could be a drop-in replacement for the `pslist | findstr` line.

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use **PSAppDeployToolkit**. This will make your life much easier?